# Long term package capture

Tags: wireshark

I am looking for solution to capture network traffic under Windows without storing data block of packages.

That will be part of a network troubleshooter script that should monitor performance over 48 hours.

I used to do similar script in bash that built on tcpdump:

```
tcpdump --no-promiscuous-mode -i $netif -w $dumpdir/$stamp2.ping.pcap
```

Unfortunately WiFi interface drivers were not enough reliable, and I have spent lot of time and effort to TS Linux bugs instead of network bugs. So I decide to gave that up.

The new version based on dumpcap under Windows(PS):

```
.\dumpcap.exe -i $AdapterName -w "$outputPath.$timeStamp.pcap" -p -a duration:3600
```

Also in both case Iperf was used for generate slow constant traffic. As 2mbps traffic consume lot of disk space, capture has been restarted after ever 1 hour and old pcap file compressed to an archive file.

This part of script was working very gently under Linux, the compressed pcap files were only the fraction of the original size.

I have noticed a significant different between tcpdump and dumpcap. Tcpdump does not store data block of packages. See on pictures.

[tcpdump - package capture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0sMO.png)

[dumpcap - package capture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMCGR.png)

As you can see tcpdump stores only zeros instead of the data.

I am looking for something similar solution with dumpcap, or if it is not possible than with different tool. Only criteria: it has to be available on Windows and free/open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

*As you can see tcpdump stores only zeros instead of the data.*

As far as I'm aware, [`tcpcump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) does not write zeros in place of the data being transferred.  If you're seeing zeroes, then zeroes were transmitted.

If you don't need or want the payload, then you could use a *snaplen* with either `tcpdump` or `dumpcap` to limit the number of bytes captured.  A snaplen is specified using the `-s <snaplen>` option, where `snaplen` is the number of bytes in a packet to save.  Both tools use the same option for this feature.  If you were to limit the number of bytes captured, the resulting capture files would obviously be much smaller and you might not need to bother compressing them.

As an aside, it seems strange to me that you would use `dumpcap's` `"-a duration:3600"` option to stop capturing after an hour only to have to ***manually*** restart it instead of using the `"-b duration:3600"` option, which would ***automatically*** stop capturing to a file and start capturing to the next file after each hour.  There are other `-b` options too, which you could use in combination with the `"-b duration:3600"` option and which would allow you to limit the total number of files retained or the maximum size of each file.  Refer to the [dumpcap man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) for more information on those options.